# Using FileSystemWatcher to alert if multiple files change simulatenously

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

I am very new to powershell. The following code is created by BigTeddy and he gets the full credit (I also made some Changes using the While Loop)

**I want to know how can I create an if/else statement such that if more than one file is changed/edited/created/deleted at the same time (say ten files have been edited simultaneously) a log file will be created saying these list files has been edited simultaneously at this particular time.**

The following powershell script BigTeddy created basically spits out a log file (and on the output of the powershell ISE) of when a change/edit/creation/deletion has been made, the time it was changed and what file(s) was edited.

```
 param(
        [string]$folderToWatch = "C:\Users\gordon\Desktop\powershellStart"
      , [string]$filter        = "*.*"
      , [string]$logFile       = 'C:\Users\gordon\Desktop\powershellDest\filewatcher.log'
    )

    # In the following line, you can change 'IncludeSubdirectories to $true if required.
    $fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folderToWatch, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}
    $timeStamp           #My changes
    $timeStampPrev = $timeStamp         #My changes
# This script block is used/called by all 3 events and:
# appends the event to a log file, as well as reporting the event back to the console
$scriptBlock = {

  # REPLACE THIS SECTION WITH YOUR PROCESSING CODE
  $logFile = $event.MessageData # message data is how we pass in an argument to the event script block
  $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
  $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
  $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
  while($timeStampPrev -eq $timeStamp) {     #My changes
  Write-Host "$timeStamp|$changeType|'$name'" -fore green
  Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Append -InputObject "$timeStamp|$changeType|'$name'"
  # REPLACE THIS SECTION WITH YOUR PROCESSING CODE
}
}


# Here, all three events are registered.  You need only subscribe to events that you need:
Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -MessageData $logFile -Action $scriptBlock
Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Deleted -SourceIdentifier FileDeleted -MessageData $logFile -Action $scriptBlock
Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Changed -SourceIdentifier FileChanged -MessageData $logFile -Action $scriptBlock

# To stop the monitoring, run the following commands:
#  Unregister-Event FileDeleted  ;  Unregister-Event FileCreated  ;  Unregister-Event FileChanged


#This script uses the .NET FileSystemWatcher class to monitor file events in folder(s).
#The advantage of this method over using WMI eventing is that this can monitor sub-folders.
#The -Action parameter can contain any valid Powershell commands.
#The script can be set to a wildcard filter, and IncludeSubdirectories can be changed to $true.
#You need not subscribe to all three types of event.  All three are shown for example.
```

Comment: When 10 files has been changed simultaneously you'll get 10 notifications. It's up to you how you'll proceed them.

Comment: Does files being edited within the same 1 minute, 10 seconds, 1 second, 100 milliseconds, 10 milliseconds, etc. count as "simultaneously"?

Comment: within 1 second at most. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered a hash table with timestamps and action(create/modify/delete) as keys and file name as value. You iterate through the dictionary after a specific wait interval and you flush the entries in the dictionary to a log file.